# VBA loops to replace multible if statements

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet with a repetitive `If` statement in VBA in a `Worksheet_Change` sub

```
If Range("D5") = Range("D4") Then
   Range("c5") = DateAdd("w", Range("i4"), Range("c4"))
Else
   Range("c5") = Range(c2")
End If    
If Range("D6") = Range("D5") Then
   Range("c6") = DateAdd("w", Range("i5"), Range("c5"))
Else
   Range("c6") = Range(c2")
End If
```

it will repeat from `D5` to `D150` my question is can I rewrite this in a loop instead of repeating the if statement 145 times?

Im not to good when it comes to loops

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `For` loop:

```
For i = 5 To 150
    If Range("D" & i) = Range("D" & (i-1)) Then
       Range("C"& i) = DateAdd("w", Range("I" & (i-1)), Range("C" & (i-1)))
    Else
       Range("C" & i) = Range("C2")
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Note to OP: you could use `Cells` which is a bit neater `If Cells(r, "D").Value = Cells(r - 1, "D").Value Then` etc.

Comment: @SJR I also would've used `Cells` in this case.